# How thick and wide does a concrete surface have to be to hold 139,300kg without problems

Tags: concrete

Im trying to make a project on how to make the Saturn V reusable and stuck on how thick does the landing pad need to be to hold the 1st stage

Comment: The folks over on Space Exploration (https://space.stackexchange.com/questions) might be able to tell you what the pads actually are.